# How to update %time% variable in Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd, command-prompt

I have a batch script for backing up databases. I echo the %time% that script starts and then the %time% it ends to a log file. Even though the script takes 5 minutes to backup our databases the end time is identical to the start time.

```
@echo off

:: Credentials preconfigured for backup-operator
net use y: \\172.16.104.201\Backups

:: Date in format YYYY.MM.DD
set DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~3,2%.%DATE:~0,2%
set LOCAL_DIR=F:\Backups\
set EXTERN_DIR=Y:\DB3\

:: Output all to txt
>"%LOCAL_DIR%SQLBackups-%DATESTAMP%.txt" (
     echo.
     echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     echo -- Starting SQL Backups %date% %time% --
     echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     echo.

    :: Backup and Copy loop
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
    for %%i in (
        DB1 
        DB2
        DB3
        DB4 etc...
    ) do (
        set DATABASENAME=%%i
        set BACKUPFILENAME=!LOCAL_DIR!!DATABASENAME!-!DATESTAMP!.bak
         echo.
         echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         echo -- Backing Up Database !DATABASENAME! to local--
         echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         echo.
        sqlcmd -E -S DB3 -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [!DATABASENAME!] TO DISK = '!BACKUPFILENAME!' WITH DESCRIPTION = 'Full backup [!DATABASENAME!]', CHECKSUM, INIT, COMPRESSION"
         echo.
         echo.
         echo -- Copying !DATABASENAME! Backup to external--
        robocopy !LOCAL_DIR! !EXTERN_DIR! !DATABASENAME!-!DATESTAMP!.bak
         echo.
         echo -- !DATABASENAME! End --
         echo.
         echo.
    )
    endlocal

    :: Delete files older than -d days from local
    forfiles -p %LOCAL_DIR% -s -m *.bak -d "-180" /C "cmd /c echo @path & del @path""
    forfiles -p %LOCAL_DIR% -s -m *.txt -d "-180" /C "cmd /c echo @path & del @path""
     echo.
     echo.
     echo -- Script Complete %date% %time% --
     echo.
)
robocopy %LOCAL_DIR% %EXTERN_DIR% "SQLBackups-%DATESTAMP%.txt"
net use y: /delete
```

Comment: use `!date!` and `!time!` as you are in brackets and already delayed expansion is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` below `@echo off` and access the time with `!time!` instead of `%time%`. That should be it.

Comment: delayed expansion is already set but is not used for date and time :)

Comment: Oh, you're right. So just replace `%time` with `!time!`.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile variables are unreliable. Any program, user, or install can kill them. Use tried and true methods.

```
for /f "Delims=" %A in ('time /t') do Set MyTime=%A
```

For a way that will work on all computers.

Comment: Your answer don't address the posted problem. Also, I am afraid I don't understand what you mean with "Volatile variables are unreliable". There are tons of programs that use variables like CD, DATE, TIME, RANDOM, ERRORLEVEL, etc. everyday with not a single problem...